# In GraphQL how to query entries where related entry has a specific value

Tags: relations, relatedto, graphql

Lets have this query:

```
query test {
  entries(section: "vacancies") {
    title
    ... on vacancies_vacancies_Entry {
      description
      organisation {
        title
        ... on organisations_organisations_Entry {
          organisationType
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now how would I go about only displaying **vacancies** from an **organisation** that has a specific **organisationType** . I've had a quick read through graphQl docs and couldn't find anything that could help.

I guess I can first query organisations, get their **IDs** and then pass it to **relatedTo** parameter to another query, but that's 2 API requests each time I want to make a query. Is it possible to somehow use one graphQL query as a parameter in another graphQl query? Are there any better solutions to this?

Comment: Would really like to know this also, as it would be a very common use-case. This is similar to a simple join in SQL, e.g. "select * from x join y on y.xid=x.id and y.type=2".

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am hitting the same wall. I need to grab related Matrix blocks, but in order to get those related blocks, I need to send over an entry element or an entry id. I'd rather not have to run two queries every time. Argh.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 1.5+ years old but I landed here looking for something similar and think I found the answer: `relatedToEntries`.
In the docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#relations

Something like this (replacing 'attributeHandle' and "valueYouWant"):

```
query test {
  entries(section: "vacancies", relatedToEntries({attributeHandle: "valueYouWant") {
    title
    ... on vacancies_vacancies_Entry {
      description
      organisation {
        title
        ... on organisations_organisations_Entry {
          organisationType
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Works for me. Hope that helps get someone on the right path!